# 503 and 400 on uploading images in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Recently I experienced two problems in uploading files to my Java gae app.
I'm using the tecnique described in the [blobstore doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview).

1. With regular files, occasionally (let's say 15% of times) the client receives a "503 Service Unavailable".
2. With high resolution images (example 7000x10000) the client always receives a "400 Bad Request".

On both cases on the server there are no error messages logged, the blobs are written correctly, but the successPath url (the callback of [createUploadUrl](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService.html#createUploadUrl%28java.lang.String%29)) is never called. It seems that the GAE endpoint handling the upload crashes for some reasons.

My client is a js XMLHttpRequest, wrapped in GWT:

```
public native void uploadWithXMLHttpRequest(UploadForm uploadForm) /*-{
    var fd = new FormData();
    var files = uploadForm.@mypackage.UploadForm::getFiles()();  
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        fd.append("uploadFile"+i, files[i]);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xhr.upload.addEventListeners... omitted
    xhr.open("POST", uploadForm.@mypackage.UploadForm::getUploadUrl()());
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Any ideas for possible causes and solutions/workarounds?
Thx.

Comment: Show us some code! Particularly since you're using javascript to send your uploads.

Comment: Send me your app id and a blob key of a blob that you think was uploaded correctly but your success URL was not called.

Comment: App id: maptoapp.


400 blob key(400 responses happens when uploading high resolutions pictures):

AMIfv96gQvVD3xPl8IAUBZHwESNBAeeyZbxYWJD2BaxI688GkwNJXR6Lg7yx7pX8efb16YskBE7ZUVGYuUkXwSSXJ3uko6OnGKO79EuC-LupVC_gG2CaajOMBhJcQctXzsjI_MPu16ZdorDkGp-uK7c4o6BYqHxlXw

503 blob key (503 responses happens kind of randomly. with the same pic usually works correctly):

AMIfv957XZKBtl5C9RB19nntlrUi4bGfY8EPE8Rfidik0dlD5jPmeGgcLyqc2ye9WICIy063ZMoZRGIQkbVpCTM4EL7dUFzazWz2Irsn14iLKx2uBrJyYhl0qsrvRWxVa_KpMS6BGiH0N1c66XGPlkqoCo9jXPcBsg

I uploaded both files right now.

Comment: So the 400 was generated by your app - you can see it in your logs (the entry has a timestamp of 2012-05-23 23:37:44.915).  The 503 was a transient error on our side, most likely due to the fact you're using M/S datastore rather then HRD.

Comment: Hi Stuart, I work with Bebo and we are really in troubles at the moment: we have a failure rate close to 100%. I am already working on the migration to HRD, but we stored the keys as String and there's a lot of code to write. Is there another way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is being discussed in a GAE ticket opened by another user having the same problem: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7619 (btw, the bug tracker system has a "start" feature, which allows you to vote for the ticket and receive notifications)

Comment: The ticket linked here is fixed. My application experiencing similar problem (but using HRD datastore), doesn't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason:

1 You uploading large file (> 1MB) and writing it all. You should write it portinal: 1 write = 1MB.

2 Your request takes longer than 30 sec - use backend.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the 503 is caused by errors when we write the upload info into your datastore. As you are using M/S datastore then transient errors are expected from time to time. I suggest you convert your app to HRD to minimize the chances of there being errors related to writing the upload information to your datastore.

The 400 error was generated by your app & is in your application logs.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the 400 log, sorry. After further investigation, it seems that the reason of it is a IllegalArgumentException from ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(), when the parameter is a valid blob key of a high resolution image. Unfortunately now ALL the uploads generate a 503, so I can't test it and my app is pratically blocked, very frustrating.

Comment: get_serving_url only works with images < 50 megapixels. If you images are larger you'll need to downsize them before calling get_serving_url.

Comment: I didn't see at all this constraint in the doc. Is it written somewhere?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/overview#Quotas_and_Limits

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google Cloud Storage, since the blob store service has lot of problem, so google is trying to migrate uses from Blob to GCS support

I guess the image resolution can't exceed 8000 in the app engine blob store that is the reason it caused.